# How to hide specific repetitive changes in Github?

Tags: github

So, I'm setting up Github for my game project in Core, and I've got a large chunk of changes that seem to be largely just the following difference:

```
- SerializationVersion: 97
+ SerializationVersion: 98
```

Is there any way to filter out this type of trivial change from the changes view? There's over 300 of them and I'd rather not go looking for a needle in a haystack here.

Comment: Where are you hoping to filter out or hide these changes? Regardless, I don't believe any of the pages in GitHub that show differences allow you to filter or hide particular changes based e.g. on number of characters changed. But there's likely a way to do so via the command line, if that's at all useful for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.